# Has GridActionsCellItem error with props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I'm having issue when passing props in the

```
GridActionsCellItem
```

in

```
'@mui/x-data-grid';
```

colums;

```
   {
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      width: 80,
      getActions: (params: any) => [
        <GridActionsCellItem
        icon={<DeleteIcon />}
        label="Delete"
        onClick={test(params.id)}
        showInMenu
      />,
      <GridActionsCellItem
      icon={<DeleteIcon />}
      label="Delete"
      onClick={test(params.id)}
      showInMenu
    />,
      ],
    },
```

Error that im having

Type '{ icon: Element; label: string; onClick: () => void; showInMenu: true; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<{ label: string; icon?: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | undefined; } & { showInMenu: true; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>, "label" | ... 276 more ... | "divider">': nonce, onResize, onResizeCapture

i want to have empty colum with 3 dots that open a dropdown with some options.

Answer (score 1):

The <GridActionsCellItem on @mui/x-data-grid version "5.17.12" has some problems. So  switch to @mui/x-data-grid version 5.17.8. Everything works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).